# How to change height of Angular-maaterial components?

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying to reduce the size of material toolbar but when i try to reduce the size my title gets hidden inside the toolbar , And when i try to override mat-toolbar-row class it is not injected[Sorry for $ it wasn't actually present]

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no ways to change component height as well as other non teeming related properties.

[material2](https://material.angular.io/) implements components from the [material design specification](https://material.io/guidelines/), which consists of strict guidelines for each component.

The only things that are allowed to be changed is colors scheme.